# Can one edit a 360 degree video into a traditional video?

Tags: video, editing

I just ordered a Theta S which should be released by the 30th of this month. I can not wait to start recording 360 videos.

My question is, can I edit a 360 video into one of my non 360 videos? Just like if I were to record a video and cut to a time lapse and then back to the normal video, can I cut to a 360 video and then back to the normal video?

I am not sure if it is possible as I know there is different encoding etc, but I am yet to find an answer.

Comment: The idea isn't incoherent but I have not seen this in action. 360 videos depend on a compliant player to survey user navigational input and then modify the playback render accordingly. So, a mixed essence would consist of a portion where the player is instructed to disregard user input and just show a preset portion of the full video frame, and then turn on the video navigation when the relevant 360 portion starts playing.

Comment: Yes, see i under stand that. What is stumping me until i trial it is, the video encoder for 360 video discards html 5 as its not needed and java does not understand 360 video. I guess, more research will have to be done on the way YouTube and Facebook's players work for 360  to see if html and java are still present in the player. They more than likely are but are they accessible, are they smart enough to notice. Something i didn't want to do.

Comment: Sidenote: [YT announcement](http://youtubecreator.blogspot.com.es/2015/03/a-new-way-to-see-and-share-your-world.html) of the new feature links to this [document](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/blob/master/docs/spherical-video-rfc.md) about the metadata specs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any currently way to combine 360 playback and normal non-360 playback into a single player.

More generally, you can convert between rectilinear 360 videos and normal video.  The issue you will have is quality, because the resolution of the Ricoh Theta S is maximum 1920x1080 pixels.  This is HD spec for a normal video, but don't forget that the pixels are being used to cover the whole of a 360 sphere.  When you convert back to "normal" video, I assume you will only want a small portion of that sphere, otherwise the image will be very distorted.

If you're making SD videos, the quality should be reasonable, depending on how much of the viewing sphere you want to use.

You can convert between rectilinear and normal videos using something like [Skybox](http://www.mettle.com/product/skybox/) in After Effects.  (There are many other ways to do this, but this is the one I have used successfully).

Comment: I don't believe that he wants to transform the video image. He wants to insert an immersive video experience during a regular video.

Comment: Yes, you could be right... either way, understanding the rectilinear video format, and effective resolution are useful factors.. I'll update my answer to reflect that...

Answer (score 1):

Well i think the best solution afterall is to use any editing software 
and capture the screen while playing the 360° video so the 360 effect could be presented in the flat video. you will still need to play with the rotation while capturing the screen, just to provide that 360 effect to the end user.
by the end you will end up with a regular 2d video with some 360 effect into it.

I actually was thinking making a labels in 360 video without a scale effect,
and the only solution i think that might be working is to capture the 360 video by some editing program and then add the rest of the normal footage using adobe premiere

Answer (score 1):

The other way around. Using a 3d editing software like 3dsmax create a sphere. Apply the 360 footage to this sphere as a texture. "Film" the inner side of this sphere with a virtual cam animating its aim and focus to the points in the 360 video you like the best. Big buts now because I tried it before. This way the result becomes a little fuzzy and besides 3dsmax shows the joint of the texture -which must be equirectangular BTW- and if you are in need to stabilize the footage you will lose a considerable amount of resolution at the end. Just in case, stabilizing 360 equirectangular footage doesn't work. The usual way at least.

PS: I'm trying now with Premiere but I've read that Cyberlink PowerDirector comes with a tool to achieve exactly this.

**Confirmed**: Cyberlink Powerdirector 16 has a tool to manage 360VR footage in order to use it in a 2D clip.

Answer (score 1):

I'm researching on this too. I found CyberLink PowerDirector 16 [claims to edit 360 video](https://www.cyberlink.com/products/powerdirector-ultra/360video_en_US.html) but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: It works. You can extract 2D video from a 360 video.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for that for a while. My solution. Premiere Pro + GoPro VR Plugins (Horizon & Reframe). Works very well for me.

to understand.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is render a 360 cinema screen where I would show the 2d footage and mix this with the actual 360 footage.

Comment: That still won't play back well on a normal player though.  You'd only be able to view it on a 360 degree viewer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn your 360 video into a conventional video to create effects like overcapture and little planet, zoon and pan, you need to use a 360 video editor that supports that. I like this one http://molanisvr.com/360-vr-video-editor/2d-project-feature/